# Mongoose search for all fields with $regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Say, for instance, I have the following model:

```
    var advertise = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    text: String,
    locations: Array,
    days: Array,
    phone: Object,
    images: Array,
    age: Number,
    height: String,
    sex: String,
    categories: Array,
    targetAudience: Array,
    prices: Array,
    creator: String,
    hairColor: Object,
    eyeColor: Object,
    breastSize: Object,
    bodyType: Object,
    advertiseType: Object,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    is_active: {type: Number, default: 0},
    order_id: String
});
```

Now I have a value called `searchString`. Is there a way I can search for all fields with the `searchString`?

Right now I only know to do this with the `$or` key. However, this would be impractical.

Like the following:

```
mongoose.models.advertise.find({$or: [{'username': {'$regex': searchString}}]}, function (err, advertise) {
    res.json(advertise)
})
```

**Note** I'm using `Node.js`

Comment: Do you have the possibility to create a text index with mongoose ? I think it would be the most convenient way.

Comment: Accepted answer does not cover non-string fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the ability to create a [$text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) :

```
var advertise = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    text: String,
    locations: Array,
    days: Array,
    phone: Object,
    images: Array,
    age: Number,
    height: String,
    sex: String,
    categories: Array,
    targetAudience: Array,
    prices: Array,
    creator: String,
    hairColor: Object,
    eyeColor: Object,
    breastSize: Object,
    bodyType: Object,
    advertiseType: Object,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    is_active: {type: Number, default: 0},
    order_id: String
});
advertise.index({ username: 'text', text: 'text', height: 'text', sex: 'text', creator: 'text', order_id: 'text' });
```

To perform a search :

```
mongoose.models.advertise.find({ $text : { $search : searchString } }, function (err, advertise) {
    res.json(advertise)
})
```

I didn't tried for real do not hesitate to correct potential errors.

Comment: But this does not search all fields, only string fields.

Comment: Is there any solution for searching in arrays and objects?